Ubuntu Software is not working properly
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Ubuntu Software is taking to much time for loading and sometimes not loading properly. I am facing problems while updating apps. Apps are showing for updates but they are not downloading. Application details are also not loading. When I newly installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS then there was Snap Store instead of Ubuntu Software. And the Snap Store was working properly. But after few days Snap Store is disabled and Ubuntu Software enabled automatically. And I started facing issues in Ubuntu Software.
